# Does $E[Y|X=x] = x$ for all $x$ imply that $X = Y$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, conditional-expectation

It's easy to derive that this implies that $E[Y] = E[X]$, but can the stronger assumption be made? Does $Y$ and $X$ having the same support make a difference? My assumption is no, because $E[Y|X=x] = x$ doesn't mean that $P(Y = x|X = x) = 1$, but I can't think of any counterexamples

Comment: Can you come up with a counter-example such that, whenever $X=x$, either $Y=x-1$ or $Y=x+1$?

Comment: Or, let $X=0$, and the question becomes "Does $E[Y]=0$ imply $Y=0$?".

Comment: Let Z be random variable ind. of X with 0 mean. Y=Z+X.  E(Y|X=x}=0+x.